# How to implement enemy behaviour based on type?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am building a game which create three types of enemy.Amount them only type 3 can fire others cannt.This is my enemy class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;


public class Enemy extends MovieClip
{
    private var lastTime:int;
    var hitCounter:Number = 1;
    public var eType:Number = 0;
    private var startYpos:Number = 0;

    var nextFire:Timer;
    var enemyType:Number;

    public var bullets:Array = new Array  ;

    var speedY:Number = 50;
    var enemySpeed:Number = 50;

    var firstPos:Number = 0;
    var fireCounter:Number = 0;
    var firePause:Number = 10;

    public function Enemy(xPos,yPos:Number,t:Number)
    {
        // constructor code
        this.x = xPos;
        firstPos = this.y = yPos;
        this.enemyType = t;
        lastTime = getTimer();
        this.gotoAndStop(t);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveEnemy);
    }

    public function moveEnemy(event:Event)
    {
        // get time passed
        var timePassed:int = getTimer() - lastTime;
        lastTime +=  timePassed;
        // move bullet

        if (this.y + this.height / 2 > firstPos + 100 && speedY > 0)
        {
            speedY *=  -1;

        }

        if (this.y - this.height / 2 < firstPos && speedY < 0)
        {
            speedY *=  -1;
        }

        this.x -=  enemySpeed * timePassed / 1000;
        this.y +=  speedY * timePassed / 1000;

        // bullet past top of screen
        if (this.x - this.width / 2 < 0)
        {
            deleteEnemy();
        }

        if (this.enemyType == 3)
        {
            canFire();
        }
    }

    public function canFire()
    {
        if ((fireCounter > firePause))
        {
            MovieClip(parent).createEnemyBullet();
            trace((('Enemy Type : ' + enemyType) + ' and firing'));
            fireCounter = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            fireCounter++;
        }
    }

    public function deleteEnemy()
    {
        if (this.currentFrame == 2)
        {
            this.gotoAndStop(4);
        }
        else
        {

            //trace(MovieClip(parent).enemyKilled[this.enemyType-1]);
            MovieClip(parent).enemyKilled[this.enemyType - 1]++;
            MovieClip(parent).removeEnemy(this);
            parent.removeChild(this);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveEnemy);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now once a enemy type 3 start firing then every enemy start firing.i want just only enemy type 3 can fire not other enemy.How i do it?
Thanks in advance

**Addition :**

```
public function createEnemyBullet()
    {           
        var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(enemy.x - 10,enemy.y,500,-1);
        bullets.push(bullet);
        addChild(bullet);       

        //setEnemyBullet();
    }
```

Comment: My best guess with this information is the unwanted behaviour is inside the function "createEnemyBullet" could you post that function too?

Comment: what does the canFire() function really do?

Comment: Creating fire inside the enemy class @harilalkm

Comment: so you are firing the bullet on that function /

Comment: yes it is 
@harilalkm

Comment: Sorry still can't find the problem. Can you post the entire "parent" class, the class that contains createEnemyBullet function?

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you try something like this. `

```
public function canFire()
    {
        if(enemyType == 3){
            return;
           }
        if ((fireCounter > firePause))
        {
            MovieClip(parent).createEnemyBullet();
            trace((('Enemy Type : ' + enemyType) + ' and firing'));
            fireCounter = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            fireCounter++;
        }
    }
```

`